# Allow few endpoints and authenticate remaining spring security with matchers

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Below is the code I have

```
String[] allowedEndpoints = new String[]{"/preauth/**", "/.~~spring-boot!~/restart/**", "/h2-console/**"};    

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { // NOPMD
http
  .csrf().ignoringAntMatchers(allowedEndpoints) //used to allow http post
  .and()
  .authorizeRequests()
  .mvcMatchers(allowedEndpoints).permitAll()
  .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).permitAll()
  .mvcMatchers("/private/**").authenticated()
  //.anyRequest().authenticated()
  .and()
  .formLogin(withDefaults());

http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
return http.build();
}
```

This is allowing all endpoints without any authentication except "/private/**" which is expected. As soon as I uncomment `.anyRequest().authenticated()` it starts asking for authentication for all endpoints.

My understanding is matchers will go in sequence and as soon as first matcher matches it skips the remaining. So how .anyRequest() is matching which is at the end. Am I missing something?

Comment: I tried the same configuration (with `.anyRequest().authenticated()` uncommented)  locally and I was allowed to access "/preauth/hello". Which version of Spring Security / Spring Boot are you using? Do you have any additional security configuration?